# I need to translate my scientific article. Can I offer co-authorship in exchange for translation services?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, research-process

I have a scientific manuscript and I do not know how to translate it. Nor do I have the money to have it professionally translated. Can I ask another academic to translate it in exchange for co-authorship? If so, what percentage of authorship would they be entitled to?

Comment: I took a stab at clarifying the question, but not sure I got it right. In particular, I'm not sure in what field you would have to specify each author's contribution percentage. Is someone asking for your contribution percentage?

Answer (score 11):

If it is a pure language translation, then the translator doesn't contribute to the ideas of the paper. In that case, the translator can be acknowledged by name (with their permission), but is not a contributor, nor an author.

To be a "contributor" means that you contribute intellectual content - ideas.

---

Thinking more about the issue, let me suggest two potential solutions. One is to find someone and open a collaboration with them on the topic with the intent of jointly developing a paper that includes the already developed ideas. Then, if they contribute, they *are* an author and can also provide the language version you require.

Another possibility is that someone would want to do a translation, as a gift, both to the community and to you. They aren't authors, but can be thanked - profusely - for providing the translation. If the work is important enough to be shared, someone out there might be willing to do this. The problem would be finding someone with the necessary skills. They are "paid" only in satisfaction.